# How to align 2 elements where the first element fills all available space?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create the following layout, and I'm having some difficulty:

[image]

The difficulty is in getting the `Button` on the left to fill all the available space that's not taken up by the `ImageButton` on the right.

This is the axml I'm using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center_vertical">
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
          android:background="@null"
          android:text="The Button Text"
          android:id="@+id/btnText"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imgSettings"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout1"
      android:background="@null"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:src="@drawable/settings_light"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and it's appearing like this:

How can I get this to appear as outlined in the first image?

[image]

Comment: I know there is a way to do it by editing XML, but at times, I have found myself forgetting that visual editor with Eclipse ADT is pretty good.  So, try using the mouse to pull the view to fit the space available.  It generally creates the right code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this two ways - the first is a Linear Layout.  You give the text a width of 0dp, but tell it to take any space left over after the first measurement with the "layout_weight" attribute.  The Image takes the space that it needs and is then pushed all the way to the right by the text element:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <Button
      android:background="@null"
      android:text="The Button Text"
      android:id="@+id/btnText"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="left"
      />
  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imgSettings"
      android:background="@null"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/settings_light"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The second is a Relative Layout - You again give the text a width of 0dp, but you tell it to align it's left edge with the parent, and it's right edge with the image. The image is aligned on the right and takes up only as much space as it needs

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <Button
      android:background="@null"
      android:text="The Button Text"
      android:id="@+id/btnText"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSettings"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:gravity="left"
      />
  <ImageButton
      android:id="@id/imgSettings"
      android:background="@null"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/settings_light"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: These look really good, thanks! How can I get the text of the button on the left to be left-aligned rather than centred?

Comment: never mind - I got it: add `android:gravity="left|center_vertical"` to the button

Answer (score 0):

You should include `android:layout_weight` attribute. With this attribute, elements in the same layout shares the space by percentage.

So put the `<Button>` and `<ImageButton>` in the same `<LinearLayout>` so they can share the space-percentage.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center_vertical">
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
          android:background="@null"
          android:text="The Button Text"
          android:id="@+id/btnText"
          android:layout_weight:".80"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/imgSettings"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout1"
          android:background="@null"
          android:layout_weight:".20"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:src="@drawable/settings_light"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```